# How do you select all the rows between two values in SQLite?

Tags: ios, sql, database, sqlite

I'm building an iOS app where I want to retrieve all the values from my database between two dates that the user picks. So for example, I want all the rows from the 1st of March to the 5th of March. Would look something like

```
SELECT * FROM MAIN WHERE DATE = '01/03/2020' AND ENDS ='05/03/2020'
```

So from that I would hope to retrieve all data from the 1st,2nd,3rd,4th and 5th of march. Any ideas on how to do this?
Thank you

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want all the data that have "date" from 1st to 5th or all the data that have "ends" from that period ?

Comment: You'll have to change your date strings to something that can be meaningfully ordered, like `'YYYY-MM-DD'`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use comparison operators like:

```
DATE >= '01/03/2020' AND DATE <= '05/03/2020'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

1. **Date types:**

   As [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype) says:

   > 2.2. Date and Time Datatype
   >
   > SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in [Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:
   >
   > - TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
   > - REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
   > - INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
   >
   > Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in [date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

   So storing dates in a `dd/MM/yyyy` format (using the `DateFormatter` capitalization convention) is problematic because in the absence of a native date type, it’s going to store them as strings, and therefore all comparisons will be done alphabetically, not chronologically, sorting values like `03/10/2009` (or nonsense strings like `02foobar`, for that matter) in between the strings `01/05/2020` and `05/05/2020`.

   If, however you store them as `yyyy-MM-dd`, then it just so happens that alphabetical comparisons will yield chronologically correct comparisons, too.
2. **SQL syntax:**

   Once you have your dates in your database in a format that is comparable, then if you have all of your dates in a single column, you can use the `BETWEEN` syntax. For example, let’s say you stored all of your dates in `yyyy-MM-dd` format, then you could do things like:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM main WHERE date BETWEEN '2020-03-01' AND '2020-03-05';
   ```

   But needless to say, you can’t use this pattern (or any comparison operators other than equality) as long as your dates are stored in `dd/MM/yyyy` format.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show all the data that has values of column "date" between this two dates then:

```
Select * 
from MAIN
where `date` between '01.03.2020' and '05.03.2020';
```

If you want to show all the data that has values of column "ends" between this two dates then:

```
Select * 
from MAIN
where ends between '01.03.2020' and '05.03.2020';
```

If you want to show all the data that has values of columns "date" and "ends" between this two dates then:

```
Select * 
from MAIN
where ends between '01.03.2020' and '05.03.2020'
and `date` between '01.03.2020' and '05.03.2020';
```

[Here is a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/bd6b6/3)